# JDBC Query Running Indefinatly -locked <0x1b695040> (a com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter) meaning

Tags: sql, multithreading, sql-server-2005, jdbc, thread-dump

I am getting this when my web application is very slow i have taken the thread dump and found this . what this indicates?

```
"http-80-173" daemon prio=6 tid=0x5bed2000 nid=0x15f4 runnable [0x6160e000..0x6160fa68]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.DBComms.receive(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PreparedStatementExecutionRequest.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.CancelableRequest.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeRequest(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x1b695040> (a com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSWriter)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    at functions.MapViewFunctions.getMapViewPolygons(MapViewFunctions.java:254)
    at mapView.MapViewAction.execute(MapViewAction.java:253)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:304)
    at org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:190)
    at org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at net.sf.packtag.filter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:43)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Is this mean my query is executing from a long time ?? 
because after 20 minutes also i found this thread id alive.

Can anybody tell me the cause of this and fixes.

Query:

```
select isnull(b.NAME,'') as NAME,a.HUBID,a.SEQUENCE_ID,a.LATITUDE,a.LONGITUDE from dbo.POLYGON a 
left outer join LOCATION b on a.HUBID=b.HUBID where a.CUSTOMER_ID=? and a.SYSTEM_ID=? and b.OPERATION_ID<>2 order by a.HUBID,a.SEQUENCE_ID
```

Comment: Where is the query ? Ohh let me guess !

Comment: query is just a left outer join of two tables based on conditions

Comment: @ Coder of Code : Query pasted above